How can I use the application-test.properties for tests if I have another app.prop in the main project with same values?
I have REST API Java Spring application I recently started testing every function in each class, one of the functions uses MultipartFile datatype to save it in file.
The problem is that am trying to read the file from .env file --> app.prop in service layer and for testing I have the same thing. When I run the tests I get the CustomException with message "Upload directory is not configured"
public class ItemServiceImpl implements ItemService {

    @Value("${file.upload-dir}")
    private String uploadDir;

    private final ItemRepository itemRepository;
    private final Converter converter;

    public ItemServiceImpl(ItemRepository itemRepository, Converter converter) {
        this.itemRepository = itemRepository;
        this.converter = converter;
    }

    @Override
    public String saveTempFile(MultipartFile image) {
        try {
            // Check if uploadDir is set
            if (uploadDir == null || uploadDir.trim().isEmpty()) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Upload directory is not configured.");
            }

            // Extract the extension
            String originalFileName = Objects.requireNonNull(image.getOriginalFilename());
            String extension = originalFileName.substring(originalFileName.lastIndexOf("."));

            // Generate file name
            String fileName = "TEMP_" + UUID.randomUUID() + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + extension;
            // Create file path
            String filePath = Paths.get(uploadDir, fileName).toString();
            // Write file
            Files.write(Paths.get(filePath), image.getBytes());
            return fileName;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new CustomException("Failed to save file: " + e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            throw new CustomException("Upload directory issue: " + e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }

For the test I used Mock:
public class ItemServiceImplTest {

    @Value("${file.upload-dir}")
    private String uploadDir;
    @Mock
    private ItemRepository itemRepository;
    @Mock
    private Converter converter;
    @InjectMocks
    private ItemServiceImpl itemService;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    void testSaveTempFile() throws IOException {
        // Arrange
        MultipartFile mockFile = mock(MultipartFile.class);
        String originalFileName = "test_image.png";
        byte[] fileContent = "Dummy Content".getBytes();
        System.out.println("FILE CREATED");

        // Mock MultipartFile behavior
        when(mockFile.getOriginalFilename()).thenReturn(originalFileName);
        when(mockFile.getBytes()).thenReturn(fileContent);

        // Act
        String savedFileName = itemService.saveTempFile(mockFile);
        System.out.println("ACTED");
        // Assert
        // Check that the returned file name starts with "TEMP_" and contains the original extension
        assertTrue(savedFileName.startsWith("TEMP_"));
        assertTrue(savedFileName.endsWith(".png"));

        // Verify the file exists in the upload directory
        Path savedFilePath = Paths.get(uploadDir, savedFileName);
        assertTrue(Files.exists(savedFilePath));

        // Verify the file content
        assertArrayEquals(fileContent, Files.readAllBytes(savedFilePath));

        // Clean up
        Files.deleteIfExists(savedFilePath);
    }
}

Response of mvn test:
ItemServiceImplTest.testSaveTempFile:54 » Custom Upload directory issue: Upload directory is not configured.

I tried to run the tests by initialize the path of uploadDir directly in the code:
private String uploadDir = "/path/to/dir"

in both tests and service layer function, and it successfully worked.

You are using Spring features and expect them to auto-magically apply without using Spring in your tests. That is not going to work. If you want Spring magic you will need Spring to run your tests not just a simple Mockito based test. I would suggest however to put the @Value in the constructor as an argument and just use the Temporary file approach from JUnit5 to generate a directory and inject that name into the class. Which will be faster then trying to use Spring for this unit test.

The @Value is a Spring feature, your test isn't using anything from Spring so naturally the @Value won't be resolved.
If you really want to use Spring then you need to utilize it in your tests as well, although in this case I advice against it. As a Spring test is more of an integration test approach then a unit test approach.
In your case I would suggest to

Make the uploadDir a constructor argument and move the @Value to it.
Use the JUnit5 Temp Dir support to create a temp dir
Construct the ItemServiceImpl yourself and inject the temp dir into this.

public class ItemServiceImpl implements ItemService {

    private final Path uploadDir;
    private final ItemRepository itemRepository;
    private final Converter converter;

    public ItemServiceImpl(ItemRepository itemRepository, Converter converter, @Value("${file.upload-dir}") Path uploadDir) {
        Assert.notNull(uploadDir, "Upload Dir is required!");
        this.itemRepository = itemRepository;
        this.converter = converter;
        this.uploadDir = uploadDir;
    }

    @Override
    public String saveTempFile(MultipartFile image) {
        try {
            // Extract the extension
            String originalFileName = Objects.requireNonNull(image.getOriginalFilename());
            String extension = originalFileName.substring(originalFileName.lastIndexOf("."));

            // Generate file name
            String fileName = "TEMP_" + UUID.randomUUID() + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + extension;
            // Create file path
            Path filePath = uploadDir.resolve(fileName);
            // Write file
            Files.write(filePath, image.getBytes());
            return fileName;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new CustomException("Failed to save file: " + e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            throw new CustomException("Upload directory issue: " + e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }

public class ItemServiceImplTest {

    @TempDir
    private Path uploadDir;
    @Mock
    private ItemRepository itemRepository;
    @Mock
    private Converter converter;

    private ItemServiceImpl itemService;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
        this.itemService(itemRepository, converter, uploadDir)
    }

    @Test
    void testSaveTempFile() throws IOException {
        // Arrange
        MultipartFile mockFile = mock(MultipartFile.class);
        String originalFileName = "test_image.png";
        byte[] fileContent = "Dummy Content".getBytes();
        System.out.println("FILE CREATED");

        // Mock MultipartFile behavior
        when(mockFile.getOriginalFilename()).thenReturn(originalFileName);
        when(mockFile.getBytes()).thenReturn(fileContent);

        // Act
        String savedFileName = itemService.saveTempFile(mockFile);
        System.out.println("ACTED");
        // Assert
        // Check that the returned file name starts with "TEMP_" and contains the original extension
        assertTrue(savedFileName.startsWith("TEMP_"));
        assertTrue(savedFileName.endsWith(".png"));

        // Verify the file exists in the upload directory
        Path savedFilePath = uploadDir.resolve(savedFileName);
        assertTrue(Files.exists(savedFilePath));

        // Verify the file content
        assertArrayEquals(fileContent, Files.readAllBytes(savedFilePath));
    }
}

Now with the @TempDir you can easily generate a temp directory that will be cleaned up after the test has run (no more manual cleanup). Due to the change in the service you can now construct it.
NOTE: I've changed the code to work with Path instead of String!
